# Android button tap slop region

Tags: android-widget

In android, when I press and hold in a button, then move the pointer outside the button, the button un-highlights.  But I have to move it significantly outside the button; just a few pixels isn't enough.  And the slop seems to be wider than it is tall.  What are the values of the slop dimensions?  Where can I find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values, by experimentation, appear to be SLOP_X = 24 and SLOP_Y = 0.  Not real sure about the Y slop; scroll sensitivity is involved and it gets a little weird.